# How does __import__( ) function affect a python program when compiled?

Tags: python, import, compilation, pyinstaller, subliminal

I have been having trouble in trying to convert a python code to an exe using pyinstaller .

What i have been experiencing is that it the function `__import__` only imports one of the included modules during execution of the exe file but leaves other modules .

I found that, in a way , the `__import__` function is what is causing this problem . I understand that its just a function to import modules using thier names but I still don't understand the entire picture here .

How does `sys.path` tie in with this ? Is it even related ?

is it related to `__name__` ? If so how ?

What are the implications of using this function in a python program which will be converted to exe ?

I need as much info as possible since i am stuck with a project which fails to load modules dynamically when run from an executable. (the module is subliminal ) . I have opened issues regarding these in github. (links:- https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2746 , https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2747  )

Answer (score -1):

PyInstaller uses static analysis to figure out what modules your program needs (and what files are required to provide these modules). However, there are many ways in which modules can be imported (dynamically or even statically) that PyInstaller [cannot detect](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports). You must provide these "hidden imports" to PyInstaller manually.

In `subliminal`'s [setup.py](https://github.com/Diaoul/subliminal/blob/master/setup.py#L30) we can find its requirements. You will have to manually inform PyInstaller of these requirements if they have not been detected.

```
install_requirements = ['guessit>=2.0.1', 'babelfish>=0.5.2', 'enzyme>=0.4.1', 'beautifulsoup4>=4.4.0',
                        'requests>=2.0', 'click>=4.0', 'dogpile.cache>=0.6.0', 'stevedore>=1.0.0',
                        'chardet>=2.3.0', 'pysrt>=1.0.1', 'six>=1.9.0', 'appdirs>=1.3', 'rarfile>=2.7',
                        'pytz>=2012c']
if sys.version_info < (3, 2):
install_requirements.append('futures>=3.0')
```

To include babelfish, edit your spec file to include the following:

```
from PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils import collect_submodules

a = Analysis(...
     hiddenimports=collect_submodules('babelfish'),
     ...
     )
```

Comment: Im sorry , but i have already read and tested the things in the docs . I found this subliminal uses entry_points.txt to dynamically load some modules which is what is causing the issue. I found a recipe which addresses this problem in pyinstaller's website . But unfortunately  this recipe doesn't work if the distribution contains multiple groups in the entry_points.txt file and multiple names .